# running a scraper after it's finished forever

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have this scraper which I wish to run forever, and run it every time it's done. The scraper makes a ton of http requests and writes data to files. When I tried doing something like this:

```
while(true){
  scraper();
}
```

Something went wrong. My files were empty - no data. I assumed it had to be related to some asynchronous/event issue so a friend suggested that I learn about promises.

So now my scraper looks something like this:

```
(function importData(){
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var scraper = function(){
      //Making thousands of http requests
      //manipulating and writing data
      //a little try and catch here and there
    }
   resolve(scraper);
  } 
}())
```

I feel that there's a lot wrong in the code above. I don't even know where to put `reject`. One thing that should be noted is that my http requests aren't normal http requests. I am using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request) npm package which somehow makes the requests synchronous (I was having some trouble with writing the data when making async requests).

That said, I am looking for any solution to this problem (running a scraper/program forever and running it only after it's finished). But it would be great to learn to do it with promises.

Comment: `while(true)` is blocking. There is never a chance for HTTP responses to be resolved because the thread is never idle. Also  `resolve(scraper);` seems wrong. Why are you resolving the promise with a function? Why do you have a promise at all since you don't seem to be doing anything with it?

Comment: @FelixKling I am fairly new to promises and still struggling a little to get my head wrapped around them.  How would you do it? I would focus on the goal that I am trying to achieve, not so much on my bad code.

Comment: Well, if you are using `sync-request` then there is no need to for promises since your code is not asynchronous. You can literally do `while (true) {     /* Making thousands of http request, manipulating and writing data, a little try and catch here and there */ }` (assuming you are also writing to files synchronously)

Comment: @FelixKling I think that's what it was. I wasn't writing to my files synchronously. Maybe for that reason my files were empty without data. Overall, what do you think about this approach? considering the while loop will be running on server side and not on client side.